# Recursion in python and global variables

Tags: python, recursion, preorder

I'm doing the n-ary tree preorder traversal on leetcode.

I have this solution that uses two methods:

```
"""
# Definition for a Node.
class Node(object):
   def __init__(self, val=None, children=None):
       self.val = val
       self.children = children
"""


class Solution(object):
   def preorder(self, root):
       
       output = []

       self.recur(root, output)

       return output

   def recur(self, root, output):

       if not root:
           return []
       
       output.append(root.val)
       for x in root.children:
           self.recur(x, output)
```

I was wondering how to do the same recursion using one method. The solution below gives me problems. Namely, when leetcode is running testcases, it aggregates the output. I.e. the output array for test case #2 is appended to test case #1's out put array.

So:
Testcase 1 output = [Test 1 solution]
Testcase 2 output = [Test 1 solution, Test Case 2 solution]

```
test = []
class Solution(object):
    def preorder(self, root):
        """
        :type root: Node
        :rtype: List[int]
        """

        if not root:
            return []

        test.append(root.val)
        for x in root.children:
            self.preorder(x)

        return test
```

Comment: It depends on how leetcode is testing your solution. There isn't quite enough given here to know for certain. Will you please also provide a link to the leetcode problem?  Chances are, leetcode creates a new `Solution` class instance on each test case. Since your `test` list is global, it simply appends to the same list. You could define your list within a class constructor. A global variable is likely not the appropriate implementation.

Comment: In general, recursive functions should avoid using global variables (even more so than the general admonition against them). You need to ensure that the variables are always initialized before the initial call to the function. And the function is not reentrant because all instances of the function are sharing the same variables.

Comment: Leetcode problem is here: https://leetcode.com/problems/n-ary-tree-preorder-traversal/

Answer (score 1):

You should likely not be using global variables as part of this leetcode challenge, as leetcode is likely creating a new class instance of `Solution` for each test case. The easiest way to resolve this would be to create a class constructor that initializes your list. This will remove the global variable which is causing the issues you've mentioned.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = []

    def preorder(self, root):
        """
        :type root: Node
        :rtype: List[int]
        """

        if not root:
            return self.test

        self.test.append(root.val)
        for x in root.children:
            self.preorder(x)

        return self.test
```

Comment: This makes assumptions about the use of the `Solution` class that might not be justified. The desired `preorder` method seems to be defined as if it was a stateless function (with the class just some baggage it's wrapped in). There's nothing in the problem statement that says you get a new instance for every problem set.

Comment: @Blckknght the original problem statement was not provided. However, based on the behavior described by the OP, it is very likely that they are creating a new class instance for each test case. If that is what occurs, this answer is a means to address the problem caused by use of global variables. Just as this answer makes an assumption, the answer you provided assumes that the `preorder` method signature can be altered. We don't have enough context to know for certain, but in either case both answers are valid approaches for the OP to consider.

Comment: My point is, from the question, we don't know *anything* about how the `Solution` class is used in testing the `preorder` function. All we know is that the global variable remains intact between test cases. We can't tell if your solution will work, because we don't know if there's a new `Solution` created for each test case, or if they all use the same instance. I wrote my alternative because there's no reason to rely on the instance!

Comment: @Blckknght I understand your logic, but I don't feel that concern is enough reasoning for deleting this answer when the answer I've given could very well resolve the OP's issue. A variety of potential solutions is actually one of the benefits for StackOverflow. The most appropriate solution will ultimately be up to the OP in this case. It would of course be nice if the OP gave us some feedback, but since that isn't the case I don't see an issue with providing one of many potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than moving the `output` list to be a global or instance variable, you can make it an argument with a default value, so that you can directly call the recursive version of your function. You won't want to directly initialize to an empty list though, as default arguments for functions and methods are created only once, at function compile time. The same object is then reused for every call that doesn't include a value for that argument. For a mutable object like a list, that's no good (indeed, it's basically another version of your global list).

Instead, use a sentinel value, like `None` to indicate when nothing has been passed, and check for it in the body of the method:

```
class Solution(object):
    def preorder(self, root: Node, output: Optional[list]=None) -> list:
        if output is None:
            output = []

        if root is not None:
            output.append(root.val)
            for x in root.children:
                self.preorder(x, output)

        return output
```

Comment: I get a syntaxical error line 2.

Comment: Nvm. Ran this on python3 and it worked, only you need to delete ':Node'. Thank you for the explanation, I was not aware of the optional type.

Comment: @AtBay The part that failed is related to Type-Hints not being supported in the version of Python you tested the code in. It's a "newer" Python3 feature. The `:Node` part would throw an error if the `Node` type was not defined. Your question seems to indicate a class named `Node` is defined. Removing the type hint should have no runtime impact though.